# Spring XD distributed mode Redis Sentinel

Tags: redis, spring-xd

I am trying to run spring xd in distruibuted mode on 2 Ubuntu VMs. My goal is to deploy a module on one of the VMs running spring xd and make it visible to the container on the other VM(hostname: container1).  On the main VM(hostname: xd-admin) I am running redis-sentinel with this configuration in servers.yml

```
spring:
  redis:
   port: 6379
   host: 127.0.0.1
   sentinel:
     master: 127.0.0.1:26379
     nodes: 127.0.0.1:26379,127.0.0.1:26380,127.0.0.1:26381
```

In container1 I have the following in servers.yml

```
spring:
  redis:
   port: 6379
   host: 127.0.0.1
   sentinel:
     master:  xd-admin:26379
     nodes: 127.0.0.1:26379,127.0.0.1:26380,127.0.0.1:26381

zk:
  namespace: xd
  client:
     connect: xd-admin:2181
     sessionTimeout: 60000
     connectionTimeout: 30000
     initialRetryWait: 1000
     retryMaxAttempts: 3
```

When I run `xd-container` on the xd-admin host I get

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisException: Can connect to sentinel, but 127.0.0.1:26379 seems to be not monitored...
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.initSentinels(JedisSentinelPool.java:150) ~[jedis-2.6.2.jar:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:69) ~[jedis-2.6.2.jar:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:47) ~[jedis-2.6.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createRedisSentinelPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:215) ~[spring-data-redis-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:202) ~[spring-data-redis-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:195) ~[spring-data-redis-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

When I run `xd-container` on the container1 host I get

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is 192.168.33.10:26379 master is running...
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.initSentinels(JedisSentinelPool.java:153)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:69)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.<init>(JedisSentinelPool.java:47)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createRedisSentinelPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:215)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 31 more
```

I have zookeeper and rabbit-mq running on xd-admin.  I have redis running on container1. I know xd-admin is accessible from container1 because I have apache2 installed on xd-admin and I receive a response when I run `curl xd-admin` from container1.  How do I configure redis and/or my servers.yml properly for my containers to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

In my servers.yml files I commented redis.sentinel and its children and the exception went away.